# Селектор первые N элементов

Tags: jquery

Как можно взять первые N элементов (по аналогии с `:first`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[:lt](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

> Description: Select all elements at an index less than index within the matched set.

```
$('div:lt('+N+')');
```

---

[.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to a subset specified by a range of indices.

```
$('div').slice(0,N);
```